# Flutter CamerAwesome onTakePhoto event

Tags: flutter

Flutter CamerAwesome onTakePhoto event

Hello,
how do I know when a photo has been taken and saved successful?
I need the image information (File.path) to continue working with it.

```
child: CameraAwesomeBuilder.awesome(
  saveConfig: SaveConfig.photo(),
  sensorConfig: SensorConfig.single(
    sensor: Sensor.position(SensorPosition.back),
    aspectRatio: CameraAspectRatios.ratio_4_3,
  ),
  previewFit: CameraPreviewFit.fitWidth,
),
```

I tried something like this:

```
child: CameraAwesomeBuilder.custom(
  saveConfig: SaveConfig.photo(),
  sensorConfig: SensorConfig.single(
    sensor: Sensor.position(SensorPosition.back),
    aspectRatio: CameraAspectRatios.ratio_4_3,
  ),
  previewFit: CameraPreviewFit.fitWidth,
  builder: (CameraState state, PreviewSize previewSize, Rect previewRect) {
    state.when(
      onPhotoMode: (state) async {
        CaptureRequest captureRequest = await state.takePhoto();

        final request = captureRequest.when(
          single: (single) => {
            toast(context, single.file?.path)
          },
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```